# Why can't my .cpp file resolve variables declared in my .h file?

Tags: c++

I just started learning how to write C++ code using CLion but I am running into some issues using classes. To my understanding, functions and methods are declared in the .h file and then they can be used in the .cpp file. If I do it this way then I get the error message "Can't resolve variable studentName". The message goes away if I declare the variable in the .cpp file but then doesn't that defeat the purpose of the .h file? Thank you in advance to whoever can help me resolve this issue.

Student.h

```
#ifndef PRACTICE_STUDENT_H
#define PRACTICE_STUDENT_H
#include <string>
class Student {

std:: string studentName;
int gradeLevel;

Student :: Student(std:: string studentName, int gradeLevel);
std:: string getName();

};
#endif //PRACTICE_STUDENT_H
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <string>

Student:: Student(std:: string i_studentName, int i_gradeLevel){
    gradeLevel = i_gradeLevel;
}

std:: string getName() {
    return studentName;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    Student Carlton = Carlton.("Carlton", 16);
    cout << Carlton.getName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This naming convention `i_studentName` is pretty  horrible, but if you are going to use it at least use it consistently.

Comment: I'm just a novice and didn't think much of it but I will start searching for a better way to name variables and functions.

Comment: @Carlton, Welcome to the SO community. Thank you for asking a specific question in terms of short code samples. I'm not sure why your question is getting downvotes. It's a beginners question but we are supposed to welcome those as well as questions of more experienced practitioners.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, why be so harsh to a newbie? Your point is perfectly reasonable and constructive, so why not make it in a reasonable and constructive tone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getName` is a *member function* of the `Student` class. To implement it in your .cpp file, you need to properly indicate that it belongs to that class:

```
std::string Student::getName() {
    return studentName;
}
```